# Selenium [error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/.../selenium-api.js, lineNumber -> 2535, columnNumber -> 0

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to save the text of an element into a variable then get a portion of it with substring and store it in another var to use it to search that text in another page of the web.

Here's the code:

```
storeTextPresent - css=div#titol-pantalla > h2 - var_nCtr

storeEval - javascript{storedVars['var_nCtr'].substring(12,23)} - var_simul
```

At this point, selenium throws me the error mentioned in the subject:

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js, lineNumber -> 2535, columnNumber -> 0
```

I thought this could be because I had installed Chrome, but I uninstalled it and I'm still having the error.

I've also tried to add ":" between javascript and the {}:

```
storeEval - javascript:{storedVars['var_nCtr'].substring(12,23)} - var_simul
```

but still didn't work.

And tried to avoid using the "javascript" word as of an advise of a post I've found:

```
storeEval - {storedVars['var_nCtr'].substring(12,23)} - var_simul
```

but... still not working

I have searched across the internet and I've not found a concrete answer that helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>css=div#titol-pantalla</td>
    <td>var_nCtr</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>var var_nCtr= &quot;${var_nCtr}&quot;; var_nCtr.substring(6, 8);</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${test}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi. And sorry for being late on my answer (long weekend :P)

I have tested your code and it works perfectly for my purpose. Ty very much. :)